# fetching data from MLS while creating a real estate site

Tags: database

I was doing some analysis for working on creation of a real estate site.
I need to fetch data from www.mls.ca
Now i am not sure on two things:
1. Is it legal to fetch data from that site for commercial purpose.
2. How do i pull the data from the site (i. Do i need to take the data every time and keep updating my db, ii. Do i need to get any db credentials from the mls site), i am a java developer so any hints on that line would be helpful.

Please help me with the process of fetching data from www.mls.ca

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you intend to do, however, [Spark](http://sparkplatform.com/) looks promising, though. Please provide a specific question, so I can help you further.